# Local Variable retaining Value in Function

Tags: c++, c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void sum();
int main(){
    sum();
    sum();
    sum();
    sum();
}

void sum(){
    int x;
    x++;
    printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

the output of this code(in devc,codeblocks) is:- 1  2, but i don't understand why??
As the variable "x " should be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: local variables are not initialized by default. So every call of `sum()` starts with a garbage value which *by chance* might be 0 in the first call and seems to retain it's value in subsequent calls (probably because the same memory is used for stack). Try adding a call to another function between two calls of `sum()` and the result *might* differ

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard does not say that an object is destroyed when its lifetime ends. It says that storage is no longer **reserved** for the object. C 2018 6.2.4 2:

> The *lifetime* of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it.

What this means is that, when the function returns, the storage is not reserved for `x`. However, no effort is made to “destroy” or erase it. If it happens to have the same contents when you later call the function again, so be it. If it happens to have been used for something else and thus changed, so be it.

Note that *scope* is the wrong concept. Scope is **where** in source text an **identifier** is visible. Lifetime is **when** during program execution an object **exists** (in the C model of computation, meaning that storage is reserved). There is some association between lifetimes and scopes, but an automatic object continues to exist until execution of its associated block ends.

Additionally, there are special rules about using uninitialized objects (C 2018 3.19.3 1). Due to these rules, they might not act like normal memory, especially when affected by compiler optimization. An uninitialized automatic object might act like it has a different value each time it is used, even if no apparent changes have been made to its memory. And using an uninitialized automatic object whose address has not been taken results in behavior not defined by the C standard (C 2018 6.3.2.1 2).

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is a manifestation of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The variable `x` is uninitialized so its value is **indeterminate**.  You then attempt to increment the variable, which first reads the indeterminate value.  Once you do that, you can't predict what your program will do.

In this *particular* case, the stack for `sum` each time it is called happens to be in the same location in memory, so whatever value `x` had before happens to still be there.  If you added a call to `printf` in between the calls to `sum` you would probably see different results.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an uninitialized variable. That invokes undefined behavior, which means that the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants.

I copy-pasted your code, compiled it and ran it twice. Here is the result:

```
/tmp$ ./a.out 
22012
22013
22014
22015

/tmp$ ./a.out 
21987
21988
21989
21990
```

If you change `int x;` to `int x = 0` (or any other value) it will print the same value every time you call the function.